# How to choose a model's hyperparameters in terms of the variance?

Tags: self-study, validation, hyperparameter

I was solving [this question](https://www.examtopics.com/discussions/microsoft/view/20676-exam-dp-100-topic-2-question-63-discussion/) about tuning hyperparameters and I don't understand how to choose the number of hyperparameters by using the **training error** (TE) and the **validation error** (VE). Define the **variance** as VAR=TE$-$VE.

The question is the following:

You are tuning a hyperparameter for an algorithm. The following table shows a data set with different hyperparameter, training error, and validation errors.

| Hyperparameter (H) | Training error (TE) | Validation error (VE) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 105 | 95 |
| 2 | 200 | 85 |
| 3 | 250 | 100 |
| 4 | 105 | 100 |
| 5 | 400 | 50 |

1. Which value of H should you select based on the data?
2. What H value displays the poorest training result?

> The suggested answer is H=4 and H=5 respectively because H=4 minimizes the variance (variance is 5) and H=5 maximizes the variance (variance is 350).

However, I do not see how minimizing the variance is responsible for tuning the "correct" number of hyperparameters. For me it would make more sense to select the value of H which minimizes the VE for 1. (H=1) and the value of H which maximizes the VE for 2. (H=3 or H=4?).

Can someone please clarify what should be the correct choice and why?

Answer (score 1):

Babado,

Your reasoning is correct.   Whenever we pick a model (to include selecting hyper-parameters), we are balancing bias and variance. The optimal hyper parameter will minimize the error created by both of these effects.

Here's an article that digs a little deeper into the subject - https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.03-hyperparameters-and-model-validation.html.

Take a look at the bias-variance tradeoff (Validation Curve Schematic) graphic about halfway down.

You might want to read a little about cross-validation which is another way to identify optimal hyper-parameters.